# E-Mail logs for android

Tags: android

I have a non market application that has been installed in around 50 devices.

Using logcat I am printing logs .

I want the log/file that stored these logs  to be sent via e-mail periodically .

Is it possible programatically?

Is there any external tool that can help ?

I went through the sendmelogs jar but I need all the logs to be sent peirodically and not just on application crash .

Comment: A lazy answer would be to send a POST with all of the data to a webserver that sends it out.

Comment: If you store them in a file, you can send an email and attach the file, why not do this the simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out bugsense? see [this](http://mooriandroid.blogspot.in/p/remotly-get-your-error-to-your-mail.html) example; mi8 be helpful

Comment: I had tried bugsense . But they only provide crash reports i believe. Since it's an in house application i have no issues with getting the requisite permissions.

Comment: I think you can work based on [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically) example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a friendly reminder that getting logs from someone's device might be against privacy of many users.

I recommend , letting users know when they are sending you the logs, by making the click "ok" on an alertdialog. If the user says yes, you can get the logs by executing command

```
logcat -d
```

Check out http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically

other option can be periodically send the logs using a webservice.

Aman Gautam